# Interpolation between two points (2D) in Python

Tags: python, interpolation

My goal is interpolating pair of points in Python. I used the following approach:

```
def interpolate(obs,radius, n_steps):
    ox = obs[:,0].tolist()  # obstacle x position list [m]
    oy = obs[:,1].tolist() # obstacle y position list [m]
    interpol = []
    for i in range(1,len(ox)):
        prev_ = np.array([ox[i-1],oy[i-1]])
        next_ = np.array([ox[i],oy[i]])
        dist= radius[i-1]+radius[i]
        for j in range(n_steps+1):
            dr= dist/n_steps
            dir_= next_ - prev_
            dir_ = dir_ / np.linalg.norm(dir_)
            next_point= prev_ + dr*j*dir_
            interpol.append([next_point[0],next_point[1]])
    return interpol
```

This is a two 2D scenario. For some reason I am getting an incomplete result as follows:
[pair of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM8Jk.png)

Any idea which is the edge case I am missing?
Thanks in advance,
Bruno

Comment: could you share with us `obs`, `radius` and `n_steps`?

Comment: obs: pair of coordinates

Comment: Exactly. Could you include them (or parts of them) in your code, so that we can reproduce your result?

Comment: obs: pair of coordinates ( which also center of circles)
radius: radius of each circle
n_steps: resolution of interpolation

Comment: lol, sorry about the confusion. Please show us data, like ox = [1,2,3,4], oy = [10,11,12,13]. I would like to reproduce your results or parts of it to see why it delivers an unexpected result